# UiCollcetionViewCell specific segue to connect TableView show specific content within TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Hi there the question i would like to ask is there a way of creating such code in Objective C that will allow me to select a single `UICollectionViewCell` within a `UICollectionViewController` and link it to a table view that shows `UICollectionViewCell` specific content based upon what UICollectionViewCell has been selected without creating hundreds of UITableViewControllers?

A know this is not code but this is what i want the code to achieve if it is possible:

on click of collection view cell dresses show table view.

then on the table view...

if collection view clicked was dresses display dresses table view.

surely this is possible?

Also if possible i would like the code to somehow group things togethers as this will be done on a large scale i have 106 collection view cells that need linking to table views of which need to contain a minimum of 30 TableViewCells each.

Comment: Lee Sugden I help you now but I have some queries.

Comment: Do you want to show the dresses on tableView once click the collection cell?

Comment: Do you want to set the table view on another view controller or same view controller?

Comment: Yes I want to show the table view once I have clicked a specific collectionViewCell of which would be dresses

Comment: TableView on separate view controller?

Comment: I think collection view is in FirstViewController and tableView is in DetailViewController.

Comment: That's that's exactly what I want 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102077/discussion-between-user3182143-and-lee-sugden).

Comment: Tell me your mail id

Comment: Where do I find the Mail Id?

Comment: I will send you the demo project(what I tried and get the solution).

Comment: I ask you to send your mail id.

Comment: Tell me your mail id immediately.

Comment: I sent it.Check and let me know.

Comment: Kindly tick and up vote my answer lee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your question for getting solution.Finally I successfully  got the solution.Below code works perfectly.

In ViewController

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionViewSelection;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomCollectionViewCell.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
   NSMutableArray *arrayCollectionView;
   NSMutableArray *imgArray;
   NSMutableArray *lblArray;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize collectionViewSelection;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 imgArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"casual.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"collar.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"formal.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"jean.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"neck.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"pant.png"],nil];

 lblArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"casual",@"checked",@"collar",@"formal",@"jean",@"neck",@"pant", nil];
 UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
 flowLayout.scrollDirection =  UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
 UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil];
 [collectionViewSelection registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"customCollectionCell"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return [lblArray count];
}


 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"customCollectionCell";
   CustomCollectionViewCell *cell = (CustomCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   NSLog(@"The current indexPath row is - %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
   cell.img_Collection.image = [imgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.label_Collection.text = [lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.tag = indexPath.row;

   return cell;
}

 - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
  return CGSizeMake(260, 176);
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSLog(@"The touched index path os collection cell item row is - %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
   DetailViewController *detailsVC = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
   detailsVC.stringLabeldata = [lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   detailsVC.imageData = [imgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsVC animated:YES];
}
@end
```

DetailViewController

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewDressesData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *imageData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *stringLabeldata;

- (IBAction)actionBack:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m

```
 #import "DetailViewController.h"
 #import "CustomTableViewCell.h"

 @interface DetailViewController ()

 @end

 @implementation DetailViewController

 @synthesize tableViewDressesData;
 @synthesize imageData,stringLabeldata;
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
   NSLog(@"The labeldata is -%@",stringLabeldata);
   [tableViewDressesData registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
   [tableViewDressesData reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 1;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
   if (cell == nil) {
     NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
     cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
   }
   cell.imgViewDetail.image = imageData;
   cell.labelDetail.text = stringLabeldata;
   return cell;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return 188;
}
- (IBAction)actionBack:(id)sender
{
  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```

Comment: would there be a way of using this code without having to use any nib files? also by the way the code is superb and works exactly how i want it to